# How to get the width of an element which has inherit-width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a responsive website. Also I have some nested elements which used percent (`%`) width for them. Now I want to get the width of a child-element and set it as width of another element.

**Note:** I can get the width of that element which I need to it and set it to another one using JavaScript (something like this: `$('.children')[0].getBBox().width;`). But I want to know, is it possible to I do that using pure-CSS?

Here is my HTML structure and CSS codes:

```css
#grandfather {
  width: 70%;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  padding: 5px;
}
.father {
  width: 80%;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  padding: 5px;
}
.children {
  width 90%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
}
.follow-width {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
  /* width: ? */
}
```

```html
<div id="grandfather">
  <div class="father">
    <div class="children">how to get the width of this element?</div>
  </div>
</div>

<br>
<hr>
<br>
<div class="follow-width">
  this element needs to the width of div.children
</div>
```

Comment: With CSS? You can't.

Comment: @Paulie_D emm Ok, Just something else, I will create exactly the same HTML character for both elements and identical classname. But there is a problem. The position of second element is `absolute`, So how can I set a inherit-width to a absolute-position-element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cant do this in CSS only.

But you in Internet Explorer previous to version 8 it was possible:

```
width: expression(document.getElementById("grandfather").style.width);
```

```css
#grandfather {
  width: 70%;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  padding: 5px;
}
.father {
  width: 80%;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  padding: 5px;
}
.children {
  width 90%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
}
.follow-width {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
  width: expression(document.getElementById("grandfather").style.width);
}
```

```html
<div id="grandfather">
  <div class="father">
    <div class="children">how to get the width of this element?</div>
  </div>
</div>

<br>
<hr>
<br>
<div class="follow-width">
  this element needs to the width of div.children
</div>
```